# MutationObserver is not working for Linkedin unread message count icon

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, mutation-observers

I'm trying to build an automation for my Linkedin account so that whenever I get a message, I want to do something custom with it.

I'm using Puppeteer and MutationObserver inside page.evaluate call after loading my Linkedin profile with my li_at session cookie.

But it fails to fire an event even when I see the node changing the textContent.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ devtools: true, headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setBypassCSP(true);
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); 
    await page.setCookie({
        'name': 'li_at',
        'value': 'putYourSessionCookieHere',
        'domain': '.www.linkedin.com'
    })
    await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    await page.exposeFunction('puppeteerMutationListener', puppeteerMutationListener);

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const target = document.querySelector('#messaging-nav-item .nav-item__badge-count');
            const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
                for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
                window.puppeteerMutationListener(
                    mutation.removedNodes[0].textContent,
                    mutation.addedNodes[0].textContent,
                );
            }
        });
        observer.observe(
            target,
            { childList: true},
        );
    });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();

function puppeteerMutationListener(oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(`${oldValue} -> ${newValue}`);
}
```

To reproduce the issue, you would need:

1. A Linkedin account
2. A helpful coworker with a linkedin account up for messaging you OR you can change the textContent of the Node by yourself

Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: Take a look at the [MutationObserverInit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit), you'll probably need to set `characterData` to `true`

Comment: I tried with {`characterData`: `true`} and  {`childList`: `true`, `characterData`: `true`}. No luck

Comment: 1) If the mutations are within a nested descendant you also need `subtree: true`. 2) Maybe you can use puppeteer's page.waitForSelector.

Comment: Thanks guys, I solved it yesterday. Actually the problem was that linkedin removes that node first and then adds another node with the same selector with an increased textElement valaue. I added MutationObserver to the parent node of this node and it started working.